# POST Django form with AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: ajax, django

I would like to get some data within a Django form 
In order to do that, I define a javascript which is:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $('#newcase_form').on('change', function() {
        pathology_type = ($('input[name="pathology_type"]:checked','#newcase_form').val());
        console.log(pathology_type);
        $.ajax({
                url:"/pathology/",
                type :'POST' ,
                data : {'pathology_type' : pathology_type},
                success : function(data){
                              console.log(date.resultat);
                          }
              });
     });
  });
```

**It works**, I can retrieve the parameter inside the form 
**but** I am unable to post it in the URL i always have an `Error 500` and the paramater is not send to the `URL` .

here is my URL.py

```
 url(r'^pathology/(?P<pathology_type>[A-Z]{1})/', 'myapp.views.pathology'),
```

Inside my form, I have a submit with another `ajax`, so I send an `ajax` request to another `URL`

Am I wrong, or is it possible to post to 2 different `URL` in the same `form`?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: can you add the html with the form?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your problem, but it think your javascript and url.py are inconsistent.
If you keep your javascript, the url should be:

```
url(r'^pathology/', 'myapp.views.pathology'),
```

and then get `pathology_type` from `request.POST` of your view

If you keep your url, javascript should be:

```
...
 $.ajax({
    url:"/pathology/" + pathology_type + "/",
    success : function(data){
    ...
```